# Grub2 displays only flashing cursor

Tags: grub2

I have a 11.10 system was running 11.04 without any problems, which I upgraded to 11.10.

I noticed that there were many extra kernels that it wasn't using, so I removed all of them other than the 3.0.0.14 that it was using.

Since then the system will not boot.  It stops just after starting Grub with a flashing cursor.  If I hold down Shift, then it also displays "Loading Grub" and then hangs.

I have attempted all the Grub repair procedures using update-grub, grub-install from the Live CD and the Parted Magic CD, and using the Boot-Repair utility, etc...

Last night, I even completely reinstalled 11.10 from CD with a full repartition of my boot disk.

Same hang.

I'm at my wits end and don't know what to do.

I can think of only two more things to try:

1. Use 'fdisk' to see if the drive is bootable, or
2. buy another system.

Advice?

Thank you,
Randy Stegbauer

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: If something worked, consider posting it as an answer here. If it no longer applies, please delete the question.  #AskUbuntuCleanup

Answer (score 0):

Boot-repair should have fixed it! Check for removable media such as USB drives, printers with card readers, or other media that your computer may be booting from by accident.

Comment: I agree, Boot-Repair *should* have fixed it...but didn't.  This is an old system, that can't even boot off of USB.  It runs Ubuntu great...when it used to boot. :-(